# Minimum Cost Polygon Rectangulation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, computational-geometry

Given a n*n grid which contains P points, what is the total minimum cost to  cover P points using rectangles which must contain exactly K points,  cost being the perimeter of rectangles.
1. This problem seems similar to polygon triangulation with an extra constraint being that each small rectangles should contain exactly K number of points.

Comment: Is there a programming question in here? It doesn't look like it, so this question is likely outside of our scope. Even if it is a programming question, you need to show us what you've tried so far. You'd benefit from reading [ask].

Comment: first of all this is a valid  programming question. I think it has got wide application in VLSI design.I have studied min cost polygon triangulation problem and now want to learn rectangulation problem.

Comment: I have gone through this [link]( https://nanoexplanations.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/polygon-rectangulation-part-3-minimum-length-rectangulation/) but this problem doesn't satisfy all the constraints and I could not understand it properly so I have asked this question here in the forum

Comment: My point is that you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please give an example of an input and a desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect solving your problem exactly is quite difficult.
One possible approach is to use a [quad-tree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), and cease splitting 
when the next split gets too small with respect to *k*.
Although, as Thomas says in a comment, it is not clear how to
achieve exactly *k* points in each cell.

---

[image]

---

Comment: I think you need a kd-tree or AABB tree, because quad-tree is not flexible... but I also don't see a way to have exectly the correct count of points in each leaf box...